# Run the logback source example, IDEA prompts can not find the class GafferConfigurator

Tags: java, logback

I got the source code of logback version 1.2.3, run the source code of the logback-example module, or I can not find the class

> ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator

when I run the new module running example. I still have no way to follow this path. Find the class file of class GafferConfigurator

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have added the logback-classic jar for the project.
If you are using gradle, you can include it by adding this to your build.gradle

```
testCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
```

In case of maven use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I took the logback source from github, there is a logback-classic module, I created a new demo module, running the test code still prompted to find the class, I went to the logback-classic module to find the class GafferConfigurator, but could not find.

Comment: I am using maven.

Comment: I can't find this class in the path ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator

Comment: It is present in the logback-classic-1.2.3.jar. I verified it in my system.

Comment: I introduced not a jar, but an unpackaged module.

Comment: The existence of this class was not found in the logback repository of github.

Comment: It is not showing in github. But if you download the actual jar  and decompile it, you can see the Class in it.

Comment: I want to introduce the logback-classic module in my module instead of introducing the packaged jar.

Comment: I looked at the official documentation for instructions on building the logback code. I need Maven and Groovy to build the logback. I suspect that my IDEA does not use the Groovy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Because building a logback requires Maven and Groovy, some of the code is written in groovy, so when running directly, IDEA will prompt for the class not found. The logback-classic module needs to be compiled before running the code.